# javascript array/loop not working

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script>
            function onetwothree() {
                var girl = ["Ariana Grande", "Melanie Iglesias", "Kate Upton", "Vanessa Hudgens", "Miley Cyrus", "Jennifer Aniston", "Hannah Montana"];
                for (i = 0; i < girl.length; i++) {
                    var girlOfDay = girl[i];
                    var id = "w" + i;
                    var li = getElementById(id);
                    li.innerHTML = girlOfDay;
                }
            }
            window.onload = onetwothree;
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul>
            <li id="w0"></li>
            <li id="w1"></li>
            <li id="w2"></li>
            <li id="w3"></li>
            <li id="w4"></li>
            <li id="w5"></li>
            <li id="w6"></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why isnt this working its only displaying the bullet points and not the names? Im new to this i did an example like this in a a book, it worked then i tried to come up with my own and its not working

Comment: You sure got that question right ?

Comment: var li = document.getElementById(id);

Comment: It's not good practice to declare your variables inside a for loop.  I would recommend declaring them before, `var girlOfDay, id, li;` and then `for...`

Comment: wait why does it matter where i declare them? does that have to do with global and local variables? because I kind of understand what those are but im not at that point in the book that im reading yet

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
var li=getElementById(id);
```

Should say this:

```
var li=document.getElementById(id);
```

When troubleshooting problems like this, always use the JavaScript console available in the development tools of all modern browsers. For example, with your original code, Chrome reports the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined [test.html:13]
```

Comment: that is the second time ive forgotten the "document" thank you

Answer (score 0):

You had 2 problems:

1. `getElementById` is not the correct way to call, `document.getElementById` is correct
2. you weren't actually calling your function `window.onload=onetwothree;` does not work, `window.onload=onetwothree();` does work

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/den23/

Comment: From what i know about functions i thought thats how it was done and i know thats how its usually done. But in the book it doesnt have the "()" when they call it with window.onload, i thought that was weird and decided to test it with and without the "()" at the end and it only worked when it didnt have the "()", i dont know why that is and if it helps im using chrome

Comment: Justin is correct. He is setting the `window.onload` variable to point to his function (not invoke it). It will be invoked during the window’s `load` event.

Comment: jsfiddle doesn’t give you direct access to `window.onload`. Instead, you pick `onLoad` from the dropdown (which you did) and jsfiddle is directly invoking your code. In a browser, you don’t want to invoke the function yourself as it would run before the document is fully loaded. Instead, you assign your function to `window.onload` and it is invoked by the browser at the appropriate time. http://jsfiddle.net/den23/1/